# Leaving a c++ application without running destructors of global static objects

Tags: c++, c, exit

I have "inherited" a design where we are using a few global objects for doing stuff when the application exits (updating application status log files, etc ... not important to the question).

Basically the application creates dummy helper objects of specific classes and lets their destructor do these extra works when the application exits either normally or when an error was encountered (and the application knows what to do in all the cases, again not relevant to the question).

But now I have encountered a situation where I do not want to call these destructors, just leave the application without executing these "termination jobs". How can I do this in a decent, platform independent way? I do not want a solution such as divide with zero :)

Edit: I know the design is broken :) We are working on fixing it.

Edit2: I would like to avoid any "trace" of abnormal exit... Sorry for late specification.

Edit3: Obtaining access to the source code for the destructors in order to modify them is very difficult. This happens when politicians take over the keyboard and try to write programs. We just know, that "their" destructor will run on exit...

Comment: Remove the code in question from the destructors?

Comment: @MartinJames abort() raises an exeption which is very visible. I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: do you want a standard solution, or a hack? many OSs provide direct access to process exit syscalls, sometimes via wrappers like _exit or _Exit

Comment: @PlasmaHH A (temporary) hack is more than welcome :)

Comment: @PlasmaHH - that's what I was thinking,  _exit(1) or ExitProcess(1).  I guess the OP does not want #ifdef WINDOWS, #ifdef LINUX etc.

Comment: What are the chances that this app is multithreaded with join() in the destructors :)

Comment: What about `std::_Exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)`?

Comment: @Simple - does that not call the static d'tors?

Comment: @MartinJames it doesn't call destructors of static objects, no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I do this in a decent, platform independent way?

You can't.  At least not in a *decent* way.

You can accomplish this by `throw`ing an exception and not `catch`ing it.  The end result will be that your application will terminate quite ungracefully.  Destructors will not be called.  This is quite ugly, very hackish.  If your design relies on this behavior to function correctly, well not only is your design *completely demented*, but it will be near-impossible to maintain.

I would prefer setting a boolean flag in the objects you don't want to run the destructors for.  If this flag is set, then the destruction code would not be run.  The destructors will still fire, but the actual code you want to avoid running can be skipped.

---

If you control the construction of the global, you might be able to leverage operator `placement-new`.  Construct a global `char` buffer big enough for your global, then `placement-new` your global there.  Since objects constructed this way must be destroyed by explicitly calling the destructor, simply don't call the destructor on shutdown for the global.

Comment: I would be very happily aiming towards this solution (the flag) unless the source code for the specific global objects wouldn't have been originated in another department guarded by heavy layers of politics and lawyers...

Comment: @fritzone:  Do you control the code which creates the global objects?

Comment: Nope :) That's the fun part of the entire process!

Comment: @fritzone: With no control over either the global or even the construction of it, and while requiring a *clean* and *platform-independent* solution, I think you are well and truly screwed.  Any remaining solution will require platform specifics.  Nonetheless, I've thought of another way.

Comment: Unfortunately, some apps are impossible to shut down quickly in any other way than calling an OS process exit.  Shutting down some complex, multithreaded apps in a so-called 'clean' way is imp.. 'very difficult' and the code to do it is difficult to test thoroughly and near-impossible to maintain.

Comment: @MartinJames: calling exit would not help destructors of static objects would be still called (at least this is the case in unix flavor I am working with).

Answer (score 5):

```
abort();
```

> Aborts the current process, producing an abnormal program termination.
>
> The function raises the SIGABRT signal (as if raise(SIGABRT) was
>   called). This, if uncaught, causes the program to terminate returning
>   a platform-dependent unsuccessful termination error code to the host
>   environment.
>
> **The program is terminated without destroying any object** and without
>   calling any of the functions passed to atexit or at_quick_exit.

Comment: This would be wonderful solution, if it wouldn't give a big warning on the screen :)

Comment: abort() will generate a core (at least this is the case of unix flavor I am working with) will add nasty emergency logs and will cause customer escalation. So it is definitely not suitable if one wants simply restart a non-trivial application as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your comment of "we know it's broken"...

Put a global bool somewhere

```
bool isExiting;
```

Set this to true when exiting.

In your destructors do

```
if( !global::isExiting )
{
   // destruction code here
}
```

Hide somewhere, and be thoroughly ashamed.

Comment: Definitely would upvote, if not for the shaming on making potentially good tradeoffs for your program (aka optimization - which is never pretty, and should be done when you already know there is user-visible problem). What's the down side to this approach that is worthy of this shame, and is it really that bad?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to replace the global objects by heap-allocated pointers to the objects. That way, in order to run their destructors, you have to manually `delete` them. Be aware that this is of course very, very nasty. A better way than using a raw pointer is to use a `std::unique_ptr` and, in case the destructor shouldn’t be called, `release` it.

If you don’t want to change the client code which is interacting with the global objects (and expect a non-pointer type), just wrap the actual pointer into a global proxy object.

(PS: There are few but very legitimate reasons for such a design. Sometimes it’s entirely safe *not* to call destructors, and calling them may be detrimental, e.g. because it’s known that they only release memory, but will take very long due to many nested destructor calls. This still needs to be done very carefully but is not at all “bad design”.)

Comment: Regarding your editorial.  You're discussing an optimization.  This isn't really a design issue in the sense of something needing to be done (or not done) in order for the program to function correctly, but leveraging a platform to get better performance.  I'm fine with that (but would cringe), but when we need to skip a destructor call in order to have the function operate correctly regardless of performance, I'd say that *is* a broken design.  If the performance is part of the correct design and this is the only way to achieve that, then I surely wouldn't want to be connected to that machine

Comment: @John I agree, I just wanted to add this for completeness. It’s in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

It is ugly but it works:

1. Create simple maker class.
2. Maker's constructorr should allocate the object of your liking and assign it to a static pointer.
3. Make sure that nothing is done in maker's destructor.
4. Create single static instance of maker object.
5. To make things look better, make the static pointer private andwrite inline accessor function that will convert the static pointer you have to a public reference.